# python - using python-openid with django causes "Server denied check_authentication". What can I do to fix this?

Tags: python, django, openid

I am at a loss.  I believe I have looked at every possible answer on google and stack overflow, but I am still banging my head against a wall.  I have tried every different django integration of openid to no avail.  I am currently using django_openid_auth

A more full description of the error:

```
check_authentication failed: (60, 'server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none')
```

Here's the code I modified in django_openid_auth:

```
def make_consumer(request):
  session = request.session.setdefault('OPENID', {})
  #store = DjangoOpenIDStore() # Old
  djangoconnection.cursor() # New
  store = MySQLStore(djangoconnection.connection, associations_table='django_openid_auth_association', nonces_table='django_openid_auth_nonce',) # New
  return Consumer(session, store)
```

I really thought this would do the trick, but no.  For what it's worth, I have tried checking my database tables for any signs of use, but they don't appear to be.  I don't know if this is because no data was ever entered, or if it is quickly being cleaned up.

I have also tried the solution [here](http://realmike.org/blog/2011/01/02/ssl-certificate-error-with-gwibber-and-identi-ca-on-ubuntu/) and [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookShortcutsOpenIDAuthentication), although I believe the second link's solution is basically what I already outlined.  Also the back and forth commentary on that page is somewhat confusing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated for the rest of my life! (or at least a couple of days)